# How can I create local Maven repository for my own libraries?

Tags: maven-2, repository

I need to have my own libraries in Maven repository, and I only need these my own libraries (about 2-7 libs). Is it possible to copy these jars to some local folder and then use that as repository in Maven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming these libraries only need to be available for your local build, you can just install them in to your repo from the cmd line:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=<your_group_name> -DartifactId=<your_artifact_name> -Dversion=<snapshot> -Dfile=<path_to_your_jar_file> -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

You can use any artefact/group/version you likr - but these then need to be used in your pom when listing the dependency

Comment: Thank you! What if file is updated, will updated version of file be included instead of some cached version ?

Comment: @newbie. The files should NEVER change unless they are snapshots. This is required to ensure the integrity of your builds. If a file does change, it should be installed again with a new version, and you use that new version in your pom.